# Connect to a Wi-Fi modem without password

Tags: wifi, router

I want to know if I can put my laptop MAC address to my Wi-Fi router and when my Wi-Fi password changed, connect to my router without entering new password? I use TP-link router.

Answer (score 3):

The WiFi password is actually a shared secret key that is used to encrypt the data between your machine and wireless access point.

MAC Address filtering only prevents honest wireless clients from connecting to your network. An attacker can spoof his or her MAC Address to a trusted client's, or the MAC Address of the wireless access point, in order to bypass the filter.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You can use mac address filtering, but that's only to filter out the mac addresses.

Comment: I think that this depends on the firmware in router - RouterOS can do that, I think.

Comment: Whitelisting is certainly possible, but it's trivial to bypass. I don't know of anything that lets you require WPA except for certain MACs, and there would be serious security issues.